# Is this recursive implementation of bubble sort inefficient, and how could it be improved if possible?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Yesterday I came across a recursive implementation of bubble sort, which looks elegant at first glance:

```cpp
template <class T> void bubblesort_recursive(T data[], const int n){
    if(n==1) return;
    else{
        bubblesort_recursive(data+1, n-1);
        if(data[1]<data[0]) swap(data[1],data[0]);
        bubblesort_recursive(data+1, n-1);
    }
}
```

However, I soon realized that it calls the recursive case twice and the time recursive relation for its time complexity seems to be following T(n)=2T(n-1)+c, which leads to exponential time complexity. However, bubble sort usually leads to n^2 time complexity. Is my analysis somewhere wrong or is this just an inefficient implementation of bubble sort? If it was the latter one, how could it be improved?

Comment: *Yesterday I came across a recursive implementation of bubble sort, which looks elegant at first glance:* -- There is nothing elegant about bubble sort.   Bubble sort is O(n^2) -- anything faster than that, it isn't bubble sort.

Comment: Try walking through this algorithm with `n=5`. You should see some obvious waste in the second call to `bubblesort_recursive`. It's not clear what your criteria for "improved" are.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Do you mean anything slower than O(n^2)?

Comment: "*how could it be improved?*" - if the code works, and you just want to optimize it, then that is a question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: *"how could it be improved"* - Don't bother with recursion, and more-so, don't bother with bubble-sort. It has an *extremely* limited viable use case. No matter how much "elegant" lipstick you put on that pig, it's still a pig.

Comment: Can you share the link where you found it?

Comment: That is not bubblesort, despite the name of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which leads to exponential time complexity.

True.

> However, bubble sort usually leads to n^2 time complexity.

True.

> how could it be improved?

If you are looking for a recursive implementation of bubble sort that has O(²) complexity, then we need to distinguish two processes:

1. One sweep of bubbling
2. Repeating this with shorter sections of the array

Both can be implemented in a recursive way, but they will be distinct recursions:

```
template <class T> void bubble_recursive(T data[], const int n) {
    if (n == 1) return;
    if (data[1] < data[0]) swap(data[1], data[0]);
    bubble_recursive(data + 1, n - 1);
}

template <class T> void bubblesort_recursive(T data[], const int n) {
    if (n == 1) return;
    bubble_recursive(data, n);
    bubblesort_recursive(data, n-1);
}
```

You can also add the *early exit* feature that some bubble sort implementations have: when a single sweep for bubbling shows that no swap had to be performed, then we know the array is sorted, and can stop doing more iterations on shorter sections:

```
template <class T> bool bubble_recursive(T data[], const int n) {
    if (n == 1) return false;
    bool must_swap = data[1] < data[0]; 
    if (must_swap) swap(data[1], data[0]);
    return bubble_recursive(data + 1, n - 1) || must_swap;
}

template <class T> void bubblesort_recursive(T data[], const int n) {
    if (bubble_recursive(data, n))
        bubblesort_recursive(data, n - 1);
}
```